# Reversing positive sequences in array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, sequence

So, I have a cycle that goes over an array and should reverse the sequence of consecutive positive numbers, but it seems to count excess negative number as a part of a sequence, thus changing its position. I can't figure the error myself, and will be happy to hear any tips!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int Arr[100];
int Arr2[100];
int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));
int n, x;
bool seq = false;
int ib = 0;
printf("Starting array\n");
for (n = 0; n < 100; Arr[n++] = (rand() % 101) - 50);
for (n = 0; n < 100; printf("%3d ", Arr[n++]));
putchar('\n');
for (n = 0; n < 100; n++) //sorting
{
    if (Arr[n] > 0) //check if the number is positive
    {
        if (seq == false) //if it isn't the part of a sequence
        {
            seq = true; ib = n; //declare it now is, and remember index     of sequence's beginning
        }
        else
            seq = true; //do nothing if it isn't first
    }
    else //if the number is negative
    {   
        if (seq==true) //if sequence isn't null
        for (x = n; ib <= n; ib++, x--) //new variable so that n will stay unchanged, 
          number of iterations = length of sequence
        {
            Arr2[x] = Arr[ib]; //assigning array's value to a new one,
            reversing it in the process
        }
        seq = false; //declaring sequence's end 
        Arr2[n + 1] = Arr[n + 1]; //assigning negative numbers at the same place of a new array
    }
}
printf("Modified array\n");
for (n = 0; n < 100; printf("%3d ", Arr2[n++]));
putchar('\n');
system('pause');
return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you include the code where `n , arr[], arr2[], seq and x` are declared?

Comment: `if (seq = false)` --> `if(seq == false)`

Comment: Yep. Looks like typo. Impossible to confirm without [mcve] though.

Comment: I'm also not sure about `ib <= n;` but can't tell without seeing how the arrays initialised.

Comment: Side note: Modern compilers with the warning level turned up will flag an assignment in a conditional as a potential mistake. If you're not getting a warning for this, turn on the warnings and crank them up **LOUD**.

Comment: Sure, I added declaration of arrays and variables. Single equation sign really is a typo.

Comment: @AnatolyRomanenko so.. basicly you ignoring the negative numbers corect?  for exmple if your arr1 was -10,-1, 20,30, you want the arr2 -10,-1,30,20. am i correct?

Comment: @Yucel_K, yes, you're completely right

Comment: if thats the case i would assume that in the following scenario `-10,-1,20,-5? you dont do any swap right?

Comment: @Yucel_K, yes, it should be so, but in my program 20 and -5 would be swapped

Comment: `if (seq == false) { seq = true; ib = n; } else seq = true;` can be simplified to `if (seq == false) { ib = n; } seq = true;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following what we discussed in comments, i listed couple of rules here to shape my answer around it.

**Rules :**

- the sequence of elements can be varied. so if there are 5 positive numbers in a row within an array, we would be reversing the 5 elements. for example

`array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}` would become `array[5]{5,4,3,2,1}`

- if single positive number neighboured by negatives, no reverse can happen
  `array[4] = {-1,0,-2,1}` would result the same array
- no processing happens when a negative number is discovered.

based on these rules.
here is what I think going wrong in your code.

**Problems :**

1- consider this`array = {1,2,-1}`. notice that the last value is negative. because of this. the following code would run when the 3rd index of the array is processed;

```
` Arr2[n + 1] = Arr[n + 1]; //assigning negative numbers at the same place of a new array`
```

this is a no-no. since you are already at the end of the `Arr2` n+1 would indicate that there is a 4th element in the array. *(in your case 101h element of the array)* this would cause an undefined behaviour.

2 - consider the same array mentioned above.  when that array is looped, the outcome would be  `array = {-1,2,1}` . the -1  and 1 are swapped instead of 1 and 2.

3 - you are assigning `ib = n`  whenever a negative number is found. because whenever a negative value is hit, `seq=false` is forced.  But the `ib`, never been put into use until a next negative number is found. here is an example;

`array = {...2, 6}`

in such scenario, 2 and 6  would never get reversed because there is no negative value is following this positive sequence.

4 -  consider this scenario `arr = {-10,-1,....}` this would result in `arr = {0,-1,....}`. This happens because of the same code causing the undefined behaviour problem mentioned above.

```
 `Arr2[n + 1] = Arr[n + 1];`
```

**Suggestion**
Most of the problems mentioned above is happening because you are trying to figure out the sequence of the positive numbers when a negative number is found.

```
 else //if the number is negative
    {   
        if (seq==true) //if sequence isn't null
        for (x = n; ib <= n; ib++, x--) //new variable so that n will stay unchanged, 
          number of iterations = length of sequence
        {
            Arr2[x] = Arr[ib]; //assigning array's value to a new one,
            reversing it in the process
        }
```

you should completely get rid of that and completely ignore the negative numbers unless you forgot to mention in your question some key details. instead just focus on the positive numbers. I'm not going to send you the entire code but here is how I approached the problem. feel free to let me know if you need help and I would be more then happy to go through in detail.

- start your for loop as usual.

  `for (n = 0; n < 100; n++) //sorting`
  `{`
- don't try to do anything when an element in an array is a negative value.
  `if (Arr[n] > 0) //check if the number is positive`
- if the number is positive. create recording the sequence indices. for one, we know the sequence will start at `n` once the `if (Arr[n] > 0) true. so we can do something like this;

  `int sequenceStart = n;`
- we also need to know when the positive number sequence ends.

  `int sequenceEnd = sequenceStart;`
- the reason for `int sequenceEnd = sequenceStart;` is because we going to start using the same `n` value to start with. we can now loop through the array and increment the `sequenceEnd` until we reach to a negative number or to the end of the array.

  ```
      while (currentElement > 0)
      {
          n++;//increment n
          if(n < arraySiz) //make sure we still in the range
          {
              currentElement = Arr[n]; // get the new elemnet
              if (currentElement > 0)
              {
                  sequenceEnd++;
              }

          }
          else
              break;     // we hit to a negative value so stop the while loop.

      }
  ```
- notice the `n++;//increment n` this would increment the n++ until we reach to the negative number. which is great because at the end of the sequence the for loop will continue from the  updated `n`
- after the while loop, you can create an array that has the same size as the number of sequences you iterated through. you can then store the elements from starting `arr[sequenceStart]` and `arr[sequenceEnd]` this will make the reversing the sequence in the array easier.